# nodejs[via require('Net')]: how do i know the socket receive all data if i not call socket.end()

Tags: node.js, socket.io

many people said: you can use socket.on('end',...) to get all chunks, but I want the socket keep connecting, so the event 'end' never fired. 
how do I know I reveived all data on socket.on('data',...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the underlying protocol. You have to have some format/layout to the data so that you know how to parse it. For example, you might have newline-delimited messages or you might have a length-prefixed messages.

Comment: it means i have to append some 'message-formatted' before send each piece?

Comment: but i send the file data like 'client.send(fileData)', do not send by piece of piece. the nodejs help me split them when socket.on('data',..) that be called many times.

Comment: If that's the case then most likely you do not have any structure to the data. You will need to choose a protocol of some kind if you are not closing the socket after the transfer of the data. If it's textual data, you could use newline-delimited JSON for example, or for binary data you could use a [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value)-style protocol. There's many different options to choose from.